# How to disable PCIe device at boot?

Tags: udev, suspend, pci

I'm trying to debug an issue with resuming from suspend with an NVIDIA graphics card. [This thread](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/kernel-5-6-system-freeze-when-resuming-from-suspend-or-hibernate/121630/19) leads me to believe it's an issue with the audio device from the card's HDMI out. I want to disable the device, but udev rules and kernel parameters have no effect. How can I either troubleshoot these methods not working or use another way to disable the device so that I can absolutely rule out the possibility that it's causing my issue?

`sudo lspci -vv` output for my device in question (irrelevant fields removed):

```
58:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 3800
    Control: (...)
    Status: (...)
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 18
    IOMMU group: 19
    Region 0: Memory at 61080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: (...)
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

`lspci -nns 58:00.1`:

```
58:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:10fa] (rev a1)
```

What I've tried:

- udev rule:

```bsh
cat /etc/udev/rules.d/10-remove-nvidia-audio.rules 
ACTION==“add”, KERNEL=="0000:58:00.1", SUBSYSTEM=="pci", RUN="/bin/sh -c ‘echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:58:00.1/remove’"
```

Running the RUN command manually does disconnect the device but the suspend issue still exists, and I have no way of determining whether the device is reconnected on resume (`journalctl` only logs up to the suspend operation, does not log anything about resume, assuming that's because I have to force power off to use my computer again). Is there something else I need to do to have a udev rule take effect?

- kernel parameter, trying [this method](https://superuser.com/questions/914810/how-to-disable-a-plugged-in-pci-e-graphic-card-on-os-level#:%7E:text=to%20enable%20it.-,custom%20way,-If%20that%27s):

```
pcistub=pci-stub.ids=10de:10fa
```

I can't use the other method outlined in the answer I looked at, because `snd_hda_intel` is used for my actual audio output as well.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually have these "smart quotes" in your `udev` rule?

Answer (score 1):

I got this done by creating the systemd service that removes device upon boot.

The body of the service looks like the following:

```
# systemctl cat remove-nvidia
# /etc/systemd/system/remove-nvidia.service
[Unit]
Description=removes pci nvidia upon boot

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=root
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c "echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/remove"
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You need to reload daemons:

```
 # systemctl daemon-reload
```

And enable the service

```
# systemctl enabled remove-nvidia
```

The result will be separate service that removes the pci VGA (in my case)

The id of pci device can be found with `lspci -vv`

good luck

Comment: This works for me, thanks! The `udev` based approach killed gnome display manager at start. I've used this `WantedBy=basic.target`, which should happen earlier. Dunno if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Everything almost correct. Just don't put last `'` in line and it must be there:

- Create the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-zz.rules` (to ensure it is executed as a last rule).
- Then add:

  ```
  ACTION==“add”, KERNEL=="0000:58:00.1", SUBSYSTEM=="pci", RUN="/bin/sh -c ‘echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:58:00.1/remove"
  ```

  - `0000:58:00.1/remove'"` - is not working.
  - `0000:58:00.1/remove"` - this is OK

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however that the closing single-quote is required, because it terminates the opening single-quote just after `/bin/sh -c`.